# Float in csv file with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have one column like that in my csv :

```
Last Mont Evolution (%)
0.00%
4.35%
4.17%
0.00%
7.29%
6.21%
4.10%
0.00%
-0.03%
2.78%
2.46%
-1.09%
19.18%
12.32%
```

I want to extract values higher than 4%, so I do this :

```
awk '$1>4 {print $1}' file.csv | sort -r -n
```

The output is : `7.29% 6.21% 4.35% 4.17% 4.10%`

But where are the values `19.18%` and `12.32%` ?

Can you help me ?

Comment: You don't have numbers, you have strings, because `%` is not a number. In that situation, `awk` is doing string comparison, and the string `1` (the first char of `19.18%`) is not "greater than" 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to do the `-F%`, you can let awk "convert" your strings to numbers:

```
awk '$0+0>4' file
```

This will output all percentage greater than `4%`. If you want the output to be sorted, pipe to `sort`

Answer (score 1):

Because of the percent sign, you are dealing with strings.  Tell `awk` and `sort` to use percent as a delimiter and everything works:

```
awk -F% '$1>4 {print $1}' file.csv | sort -t% -r -n
```

Output:

```
19.18
12.32
7.29
6.21
4.35
4.17
4.10
```